# Getting the table name of a row from a mysql query that grabs from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some PHP/MySQL code that pulls data from multiple different tables (using Inner Joins). It looks something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (key)";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
   echo $row[1];
}
```

So the code is simple enough, but what I want to do is echo the table each row is in inside of that while loop, since it could be in one of 2 tables.

I saw there was some old mysql functions like mysql_field_table and mysql_tablename that would do the trick, but they all seem to be deprecated.

Would appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AS` keyword to rename all columns.

```
$select_clause = '';
$tables = array('tblA', 'tblB');
foreach($tables as $tbl) {
    mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $tbl);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc())
        $select_clause .= '`'.$tbl.'`.`'.$row['Field'].'` AS `'.$tbl
           .'_'.$row['Field'].'`,';
}
$select_clause = substr($select_clause, 0, -1);
mysql_query('SELECT '.$select_clause.' FROM /*...*/ ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select the data with a special identifier for each table instead of using *

```
select table1.row1 as t1r1, table2.row1 as t2r1,..... from .....
```

And inside php you could look for the strings t1 and t2 and do stuff accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is echo *more than one* field from your result table (which hopefully now contains information from both the tables.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (key)";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
{   
  echo $row[1] . " " . $row[2];
}
```

...and then `$row[3]` etc...

Or access the column name/field by the *column name* or alias provided by `AS`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (key)";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) 
{   
  echo $row["c_name1"] . " " . $row["c_name2"];
}
```

Where "*c_name1*" and "*c_name2*" are your column names.